# Linking MEX (MATLAB) with Eigen and Intel MKL

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, mex, intel-mkl

I am trying to use the Eigen c++ library together with Intel MKL in MATLAB Mex. So far, I have managed to use the Eigen library in Mex. However, I am having some problems to link/run when the Intel MKL is included. To create the compiled code, I have run the following in the ubuntu terminal (same directory when the MATLAB and MEX c++ file is):

```
mex CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -Ofast -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp -L$/home/.../intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl" -I$/home/.../intel/mkl/include -I/home/.../Downloads/eigen-eigen-323c052e1731/ -R2018a trial_Eigen_Mex.cpp
```

The code did compile, however, I am getting the following error in MATLAB while using mex code:

Invalid MEX-file '/home/.../Documents/MATLAB/Work_2020/2020_01_06_Matlab_with_Cpp/trial_Eigen_Mex.mexa64': libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory

Note: Before, running the mex code, I have set the environment variable of intel MKL by running the following on terminal:

```
. /home/.../intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64 lp64
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong? Moreover, I am also not sure if the linking is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You might need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable before starting MATLAB, to point at the location of the shared library that needs to be linked.

Comment: Thanks!! It works after setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable